# Setting variable column size in bar highchart (Rshiny)

Tags: r, highcharts, shiny

I have a question relating to plot configuration in `Rshiny`. Basically, I have a bar chart and I would like to set the width for some columns and for the same X value. 
Here is the simplified and reproducible example of the code:

```
library("shiny")
library("highcharter")

data(citytemp)

ui <- fluidPage(
    h1("Highcharter EXAMPLE"),
    fluidRow(
        column(width = 8,
               highchartOutput("hcontainer",height = "500px")
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    data <- citytemp[,c("month","tokyo","new_york")]
    output$hcontainer <- renderHighchart({
        chart <-  highchart() %>% 
            hc_chart(type = "bar") %>% 
            hc_title(text = "Monthly Average Temperature for TOKYO") %>% 
            hc_subtitle(text = "Source: WorldClimate.com") %>% 
            hc_xAxis(categories = c('Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                                    'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec')) %>% 
            hc_yAxis(title = list(text = "Temperature (C)"))

        hc <- chart %>% hc_add_series(yAxis=0,name="Tokyo",data = data$tokyo)%>%
                        hc_plotOptions(bar = list(
                            pointWidth=10,
                            dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE)
                        ))

        hc <- hc %>% hc_add_series(yAxis=0,name="NY",data = data$new_york)%>%
            hc_plotOptions(bar = list(
                pointWidth=0,
                dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE)
            ))

        return(hc)
})
} 

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I investigated and a simple way to do this is to change the `hc_plotOptions`. However, when I change the `pointWidth` for one series, it is applied to both. Is there a way to apply the wanted width only to one series? Thank you very much for your help!
Best, Madzia

Comment: I am not sure about highcharter, but in standard highcharts you should be able to change series.pointWidth inside series itself (so in addSeries paramters), look at this example: http://jsfiddle.net/41yh2689/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the `pointWidth` within the series itself when you are adding it. e.g. `hc_add_series(pointWidth=10,...`

```
rm(list = ls())
library("shiny")
library("highcharter")

data(citytemp)

ui <- fluidPage(
  h1("Highcharter EXAMPLE"),
  fluidRow(
    column(width = 8,highchartOutput("hcontainer",height = "500px")
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  data <- citytemp[,c("month","tokyo","new_york")]
  output$hcontainer <- renderHighchart({
    chart <-  highchart() %>% 
      hc_chart(type = "bar") %>% 
      hc_title(text = "Monthly Average Temperature for TOKYO") %>% 
      hc_subtitle(text = "Source: WorldClimate.com") %>% 
      hc_xAxis(categories = c('Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun',
                              'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec')) %>% 
      hc_yAxis(title = list(text = "Temperature (C)"))

    hc <- chart %>% hc_add_series(pointWidth=10,yAxis=0,name="Tokyo",data = data$tokyo)%>%
      hc_plotOptions(bar = list(dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE)))

    hc <- hc %>% hc_add_series(pointWidth=0,yAxis=0,name="NY",data = data$new_york)%>%
      hc_plotOptions(bar = list(dataLabels = list(enabled = TRUE)))

    return(hc)
  })
} 

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

[image]

Comment: Hello ! Thank you very much for your help ! It works well ! Best, Madzia